# max-flow non-bipartie graph matching

Tags: algorithm, matching

I have learned the algorithm for application of max-flow to find maximum matching in bipartite graph. just add s connected to all nodes in L, and t connected to all nodes in R. Then connect nodes in L to those in R with weight all be 1.

But I am wondering , Why it does not work for non-bipartie graph?

We could repeat nodes V as V' connect v\in V->v' \in V' if (v,v') \in E.

s- V - V' - t

then max-flow is 2times the maximum matching?

It is right? what is wrong with it?

Comment: No that doesn't work. The [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_general_graphs) for max matching in general graphs are more complicated than that

Comment: I am just wondering could you point out why it does not work>?thanks

Comment: Try it in an odd cycle.